GitHub Actions Cannot upload file to Google Cloud Storage
Issue
I’m trying to automate a workflow in GitHub Actions that zips a folder, saves it as an artifact, and then uploads it to Google Cloud Storage.
However, I keep encountering a CommandException: No URLs matched error when running gsutil cp to upload the artifact.
I don't know how to access artifact that I downloaded.
I downloaded it to particular directory, but still it does not find id.
Maybe there is another way to tackle this problem ?
Error
CommandException: No URLs matched: ./downloads/jobs.zip
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

Code
name: CI Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

env:
  PROJECT_ID: "flights-429420"
  BUCKET_NAME: "flights-cicd-bucket"

jobs:

  create_zip:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: test
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
      - name: Install zip
        run: sudo apt-get install zip

      - name: Create jobs.zip
        run: |
          cd app
          zip -r ../jobs.zip jobs
      - name: Upload zip file
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: jobs
          path: jobs.zip

      - name: Download zip file artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: jobs
          path: ./downloads

  google_cloud_services:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: create_zip
    steps:

      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      
      - name: Authenticate with GCP using Service Account
        uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v2'
        with:
          credentials_json: ${{ secrets.GCP_ACCOUNT_KEY }}
      
      - name: Setup GCP CLI
        uses: 'google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v2'
        with:
          project_id: ${{ env.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}
          install_components: 'gsutil'
      
      - name: Create GCS bucket if not exists
        run: |
          if ! gsutil ls -b gs://${{ env.BUCKET_NAME }}/; then
            gsutil mb -l EU gs://${{ env.BUCKET_NAME }}/
          fi
      
      - name: Upload files to GCS
        run: |
          gsutil cp ./downloads/jobs.zip gs://${{ env.BUCKET_NAME }}/jobs.zip
          gsutil cp app/main.py gs://${{ env.BUCKET_NAME }}/main.py
          gcloud storage objects update gs://${{ env.BUCKET_NAME }}/main.py --content-type=application/octet-stream


I think file systems aren't shared between jobs (create_zip, google_cloud_services). You may want to prove this and consider moving the actions/download-artifact to google_cloud_services.

actions/upload-artifact@v3 is scheduled for deprecation (30-Nov-2024)

You should consider using Workload Identity Federation instead of a Service Account key in the GitHub Actions.

See google-github-actions/upload-cloud-storage instead of using google-github-actions/setup-gcloud

GitHub Actions are challenging to debug. You may want to consider adding steps that include a shell to enumerate file system content so that you can verify what exists.

@DazWilkin I did exactly what you said.
Thank you so much, I was googling, asking chat GPT and could not find working solution while it was so simple.

I'm pleased to hear that it helped. GitHub Actions are quite challenging to debug.

Answered by DazWilkin

I think file systems aren't shared between jobs (create_zip, google_cloud_services). You may want to prove this and consider moving the actions/download-artifact to google_cloud_services.

Working code
name: CI Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

env:
  PROJECT_ID: "flights-429420"
  BUCKET_NAME: "flights-cicd-bucket"

create_zip:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: test
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
      - name: Install zip
        run: sudo apt-get install zip

      - name: Create jobs.zip
        run: |
          cd app
          zip -r ../jobs.zip jobs

      - name: Upload zip file
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: jobs
          path: jobs.zip


  google_cloud_services:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: create_zip
    steps:

      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Download zip file artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: jobs
          path: ./downloads
      
      - name: Authenticate with GCP using Service Account
        uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v2'
        with:
          credentials_json: ${{ secrets.GCP_ACCOUNT_KEY }}
      
      - name: Setup GCP CLI
        uses: 'google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v2'
        with:
          project_id: ${{ env.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}
          install_components: 'gsutil'
      
      - name: Create GCS bucket if not exists
        run: |
          if ! gsutil ls -b gs://${{ env.BUCKET_NAME }}/; then
            gsutil mb -l EU gs://${{ env.BUCKET_NAME }}/
          fi
      
      - name: Upload files to GCS
        run: |
          gsutil cp ./downloads/jobs.zip gs://${{ env.BUCKET_NAME }}/jobs.zip
          gsutil cp app/main.py gs://${{ env.BUCKET_NAME }}/main.py
          gcloud storage objects update gs://${{ env.BUCKET_NAME }}/main.py --content-type=application/octet-stream

